# Program printing incorrectly to console

Tags: java, try-catch

I created a program which asks the user for an input (grade). I am using try/catch statements to catch InputMismatchException, in case the user enters an incorrect data type. The problem occurs during the second try/catch statement. After the program asks "Enter your percentage mark?" in the if statement and the user enters an incorrect data type. The program then reprints your grade twice and do you want to enter your grade twice.

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class CatchingException {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int score;
    String choice;

    try {
    System.out.println("Enter your percentage mark: ");
    score = scan.nextInt();


    do {
        if(score <40) {
            System.out.println("You FAILED");
        }else if(score >=40 && score <50){
            System.out.println("Your grade: PASS MARK");
        }else if(score >=50 && score <60) {
            System.out.println("Your grade: 2:2");
        }else if (score >=60 && score <70) {
            System.out.println("Your grade: 2:1");
        }else {
            System.out.println("Your grade: 1:1");
        }

        System.out.println("Do you want to enter another grade: ");
        choice = scan.next();
        if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
            try{
            System.out.println("Enter your percentage mark: ");
            score = scan.nextInt();
            }catch(InputMismatchException e) {
                System.err.print("Incorrect Input");
            }
        }
    }while(!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("No"));

    }catch(InputMismatchException e) {
        System.err.println("Incorrect Input ");
    }

    System.out.println("program terminated");
    scan.close();

}

   }
```

Comment: The inner try-catch block is unnecessary. The outer try-catch will take care of any bad input anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Your catch block does not transfer control. (e.g, by returning or throwing another exception) This means that after the message is printed, the program checks the while condition. Since that condition will never be true in this situation, it will rerun the loop using the *old* score.

The statement that *would have* updated the score threw an exception, so it wasn't updated.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `while(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("No"));` and not `while(!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("No"));`
Fixed it! Give it a try now.

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CatchingException {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int score;
String choice;

try {
System.out.println("Enter your percentage mark: ");
score = scan.nextInt();


do {
    if(score <40) {
        System.out.println("You FAILED");
    }else if(score >=40 && score <50){
        System.out.println("Your grade: PASS MARK");
    }else if(score >=50 && score <60) {
        System.out.println("Your grade: 2:2");
    }else if (score >=60 && score <70) {
        System.out.println("Your grade: 2:1");
    }else {
        System.out.println("Your grade: 1:1");
    }

    System.out.println("Do you want to enter another grade: ");
    choice = scan.next();
    if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) 
        System.out.println("Enter your percentage mark: ");{
        try{
        score = scan.nextInt();
        }catch(InputMismatchException e) {
            System.err.print("Incorrect Input");
        }
    }
}while(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("No"));

}catch(InputMismatchException e) {
    System.err.println("Incorrect Input ");
}

System.out.println("program terminated");
scan.close();

 }

}
```

[image]

Comment: but what if I want to keep asking the user if they want to input another exam mark? it needs to keep looping until the user has input no

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep on repeating asking percentage from user if user enters incorrect input data to it.

Right now, it catches exception and then enter's the do while loop and hence prints the grade once again. You might need to do the following:

```
do {
    System.out.println("Enter your percentage mark: ");//inner one
    try{
        score = scan.nextInt();
    }catch(InputMismatchException e) {
        System.err.print("Incorrect Input");
        score = -1;
    }
}while(score == -1);
```

So you loop until score is -1 (score cant be negative in exam and hence -1). So next time when you run it with invalid input, it will catch the exception and set score as -1 and then check for while condition which will satisfy and hence will again start from do i.e. asking user to input percentage.

A note: If you input an invalid number (say a string) when you first enter score then your program will terminate after printing "Incorrect Input " onto error console.

Comment: but what if I want to keep asking the user if they want to input another exam mark? it needs to keep looping until the user has input no

Comment: Yes that's the reason why you ave outer do while loop now which will handle for user choice. I just answered as to why you see grade again when you enter an invalid input.